# How do you log the output of startup.bat from a GPO?

Tags: logging, group-policy, batch-file

I'm trying to write some .bat files for GPO.  I would like a way to see the output of the script to help debug problems.  For the life of me I can't get it to log anything.

I have tried the following...

I created two batch files.  The first had one line "call startup.bat > c:/startup.log", and the 2nd one was real startup.bat file.  It didn't create the log file when I rebooted the computer the GPO was applied to.  I did a "gpresult /z" which showed the policy being applied to the computer in question.

Then I delete the first batch file and change the policy to have the Parameters of " > c:\startup.log" still not working.

The startup.bat file is just some commands to generate some output.
dir
ipconfig /all

Never mind it seems to be working now. Not sure what I did to get it working. ???

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Can you show us the actual .bat files?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the user is not an administrator and/or the CMD prompt is not running with elevated privileges. Try piping your output to a safer folder like so:

```
call startup.bat >%temp%\startup.log
```